# Android Layout not showing all Children

Tags: android

Hello dear Android Programmers

Im sitting on a app in which I want to display contacts(realized as framelayouts)
in a 2xn grid.

for that I use a ScrollView in which I placed a single FrameLayout to hold all the other FrameLayouts.

I am using FrameLayouts because I had the same issues with a LinearLayout.

For testing purposes I changed it to FrameLayout and am now setting the x and y coordinates myself instead of trusting the linearlayouts to do the job for me.

The Problem I have is that it only shows 2 of the FrameLayouts aka contacts in my app as seen in the picture allthough everything is set up proper inr egard to x,y coodrdinates, width, height etc...
[image]

The method you see here is for creating the contacts as viewgroups consisting of an Imageview and a TextView.

contactsparent is the framelayout for holding the contacts.

```
public void addContactItem(Person... p)
{
    Display display = main.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);

    int width=size.x;
    for(Person pers:p)
    {
        String name=pers.name;
        Bitmap photo=pers.photo;
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        FrameLayout lltmp=new FrameLayout(main);
        lltmp.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (0.375 * width), (int) (0.4 * width)));
        lltmp.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ImageView imgtmp=new ImageView(main);
        imgtmp.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (0.375 * width), (int) (0.3 * width)));
        imgtmp.setImageBitmap(photo);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        TextView tvtmp=new TextView(main);
        tvtmp.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (0.375 * width), (int) (0.1 * width)));
        tvtmp.setText(pers.name);
        tvtmp.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        tvtmp.setY((int) (0.3 * width));


        lltmp.setX(contactsparent.getChildCount() % 2 == 0 ? 0 : ((int) (0.375 * width)));
        lltmp.setY(contactsparent.getChildCount() / 2 * (int) (0.4 * width));

        lltmp.addView(imgtmp);
        lltmp.addView(tvtmp);

        contactsparent.addView(lltmp);

        Log.w("fdsfsf", contactsparent.getChildCount() + " x= " + (contactsparent.getChildCount() % 2 == 0 ? 0 : ((int) (0.375 * width))) + " | y=" + contactsparent.getChildCount() / 2 * (int) (0.4 * width));
    }
}
```

What went wrong here?! Why does my app only show 2 of the contacts allthough I know that there must be 10 as the (Person...p) parameter will be an array of 10 persons with which I call the method above.

The Log.v in the end of the method gives this output:

```
01-22 19:29:34.408 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 1 x= 405 | y=0
01-22 19:29:34.409 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 2 x= 0 | y=432
01-22 19:29:34.410 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 3 x= 405 | y=432
01-22 19:29:34.461 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 4 x= 0 | y=864
01-22 19:29:34.462 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 5 x= 405 | y=864
01-22 19:29:34.463 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 6 x= 0 | y=1296
01-22 19:29:34.464 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 7 x= 405 | y=1296
01-22 19:29:34.466 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 8 x= 0 | y=1728
01-22 19:29:34.467 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 9 x= 405 | y=1728
01-22 19:29:34.468 820-820/com.jaielsoft.www.emergencyapp W/fdsfsf: 10 x= 0 | y=2160
```

UPDATE:

So apparently there is this problem why I cant see the Childviews:

[image]

Then It mus be a problem with how I instanciate the ViewGroups that will contain my contacts:

```
    contactlayoutparent=new ScrollView(main);

    contactlayoutparent.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams((int) (0.75 * width), (int) (0.725 * height)));
    contactlayoutparent.setX(0.125f * width);
    contactlayoutparent.setY(0.18f * height);
    contactlayoutparent.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    contactsparent=new FrameLayout(main);
    contactsparent.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    contactlayoutparent.addView(contactsparent);
```

edit2:

as asked about the xml: there is no xml but in xml it would be like:

```
FrameLayout{
    ...
    //Here comes the Contacts layout
    ScrollView{
        FrameLayout{
            //Child1
            FrameLayout{
            }
            //Child2
            FrameLayout{
            }
            //Child3
            FrameLayout{
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show complete code with xml

Comment: as you can see there is no xml code involved as I do it all in code

Comment: see the update where you can see how the parent, a scrollview is set up

In xml it would be like

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: Don't use ListView if you want to display a Grid. Use GridView instead :D